# HTML5 Canvas - Redrawing new circles after erasing them with clip

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have a unique problem.

I am creating a game of snake with HTML5 and Canvas

I have a function that generates apples on the board randomly and removes them after a set period of time. In order to remove circles, you have to use the `clip()` function followed by `clearRect()`.

However, after you use the clip function, you can no longer draw new circles.

The solution I found was using `ctx.save()` and `ctx.restore()`. However, if you play the game, you will learn that the snake acts crazy when circles disappear and new circles appear.

I suspect this has to do with my use of the save and restore functions.

Here's the specific code in question

```
var width = canvas.width;
var height = canvas.height;
var applesArray = [];            // Store the coordinates generated randomly

// Generates a random coordinate within the confines of the canvas and pushes it to the apples array
function randCoord() {
    var coord = Math.floor(Math.random() * height);
    applesArray.push(coord);
    return coord;
}

function generateApples() {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.fillStyle = "green";
    ctx.arc(randCoord(),randCoord(),3,0, 2 * Math.PI);
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.save();           // To redraw circles after clip, we must use save
    ctx.clip();           // Allows only the circle region to be erased
    setTimeout(function() {
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
    },3000);
    ctx.restore();       // We must restore the previous state.
}

setInterval(function() {
    generateApples();
},4000);
```

You can play the game here

https://jsfiddle.net/2q1svfod/9/

Can anyone explain this weird behavior? I did not see it coming?

Comment: I think you should keep track of the objects in your canvas, clear the whole stage and redraw everything each frame.

Comment: Agreeing with @JonasGrumann. You're working against the usual canvas coding pattern by erasing just circles. Instead, keep track of all the game shapes (using javascript objects in an array(s)). Then completely erase the canvas and draw all desired objects in their new positions. **Clips are cumulative. That's why you can't draw outside the previous clip(s).**  If you must use your anti-pattern, then wrap your clips inside `context.save & context.restore`. Then your clips will be undone after restore.

Comment: this would also make erasing the snake's tail easier...

Comment: @markE it's a little unfair to call this an "anti-pattern" IMHO.  This is how games programmers had to work all the time, years ago.

Comment: @Alnitak Fair enough... **I retract the characterization as an anti-pattern**. FWIW, I'm old enough to remember having to use GDI clear sections of the drawing surface. I'm probably just reflecting my joy at being freed from having to both render and "unrender" during the drawing process. :-)

Comment: @markE only because computers are so fast these days :)  It's not necessarily so good on mobile devices, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code has multiple issues.

The code that draws the snake (e.g. upArrow function) simply extends the current path. This is a problem because the code that draws the apple starts a new path. Note that save/restore in apple drawing code does not help because path is not part of the state that is saved/restored. The code that draws the snake will need to start a new path. For example...

```
function upArrow() {
    if (direction == "up") {
        goUp = setInterval(function() {
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.moveTo(headX, headY);
            ctx.lineTo(headX, headY - 10);
            ctx.stroke();
            headY -= 10;
        }, 400);
    }
}
```

The save/clip/restore calls are in the code that draws the apple. These methods need to be moved into the timeout callback function that erases the apple. Also, the code that erases the apple will need to recreate the path (because the snake drawing could have changed the path between when the apple is drawn and when the apple is erased). For example...

```
function generateApples() {
    var cx = randCoord();
    var cy = randCoord();
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.fillStyle = "green";
    ctx.arc(cx, cy,3,0, 2 * Math.PI);
    ctx.fill();
    setTimeout(function() {
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(cx,cy,3,0, 2 * Math.PI);
        ctx.save();
        ctx.clip();
            ctx.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
        ctx.restore();
    },40000);
}
```

These changes will get you close to what you intended. However, there will still be a couple minor issues.

When drawing the apple, there will be some anti-aliasing occuring around the edge of the apple's path. The clear operation can miss clearing some of these pixels. After the clear operation, you might see a semi-transparent outline of where the apple was. You could work around this issue by using a slightly larger circle radius when clearing the apple.

Another issue is that apples could be drawn on top of the snake. Erasing the apple will also erase the snake. There is not an easy fix for this issue. You would need to store all the coordinates for the snake and then redraw all or part of the snake.

In the long term, you may want to consider the suggestions in the comments about restructuring your logic to track all objects and redraw everything each frame (or redraw everything after each change).